# How to filter array for time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of arrays that contains date object along with time, I have a record like in the this date format **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ** I want to filter my array with ascending order and I also want to store unique values as in dates.

I am having record like 2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00, 2021-04-01T12:00:00-04:00, 2021-04-02T09:00:00-04:00, 2021-04-02T10:00:00-04:00 and what I want 2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00, 2021-04-02T09:00:00-04:00
Means before time value but only once. I have used this code but not working

```
    let totalPods = [Items]
    self.totalPods.sort { (firstItem, secondItem) -> Bool in
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" // "2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00"
    
    
    let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: firstItem.startDateString)
    let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: secondItem.startDateString)
    if let safeSecondDate = secondDate {
        return firstDate?.compare(safeSecondDate) == .orderedAscending
    }
    return false
  }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why `Item` doesn't have a `Date` property directly? Because transforming each time is not recommended. Also, `dateFormatter` init & setting should be outside the closure. I don't understand what you want to keep exactly. Keep only one value per day (and that's be the earlier one), then sort?

Comment: First of all, if you want date operations, you should keep the the data as `Date`, not as `String`. Parsing dates when sorting makes it complicated and loses performance (you parse every date multiple times). If you keep the values as `Date`, you can just call `sorted()`. If you want to keep data as `String`, ideally you should keep them encoded with the same time zone because then you will be able to sort them alphabetically.

Comment: sorting is done but I want a single value from the same dates as array contains multiple values with same date but different time

Comment: I'd use `Dictionary.grouping(by:_:)`  where the key would be the "day" and a `compactMap()` on first value of each array should do the job. Then you can sort.

Comment: I would create a custom type for this holding the two dates you can extract from a single string and then use this type when filtering and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Items: Hashable {
    let startDateString: String
}

let totalPods: [Items] = [Items(startDateString: "2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00"),
                          Items(startDateString: "2021-04-01T12:00:00-04:00"),
                          Items(startDateString: "2021-04-02T09:00:00-04:00"),
                          Items(startDateString: "2021-04-02T10:00:00-04:00"),
                          Items(startDateString: "2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00"),
                          Items(startDateString: "2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00")]

// Store unique values
let uniqs = Array(Set(totalPods))

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

// filter by ASC
let sorted = uniqs.sorted { (item1, item2) in
    dateFormatter.date(from: item1.startDateString)!.compare(dateFormatter.date(from: item2.startDateString)!) == .orderedAscending
}


// You can extend your model
extension Items {
    var date: Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: startDateString)!
    }
}

// And sort like this
let sorted = uniqs.sorted { (item1, item2) in
    item1.date.compare(item2.date) == .orderedAscending
}
```

Comment: `2021-04-01T11:00:00-04:00` and `2021-04-01T12:00:00-04:00` are supposed to be the "same", and use want to keep only `"2021-04-01T12:00:00-04:00` since it's the earlier one. Your code doesn't seem to handle that.