# how to print tomarrow's date as string with custom format in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to print tomarrows date with my custom format I have used the below code but not working

```
let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormatter = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(nextDate.format(with: dateFormatter))
```

Comment: Define "not working"? WHat's your output? What's the expected output? What's your TimeZone?

Comment: You have made a simple mistake in your last line, swap nextDate and dateFormatter. And you also have a typo in the previous line. Why not try to read and understand the compiler error messages instead of posting a question here?

Comment: Also, in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298419/how-to-filter-array-for-time) you did this correctly so you could just have looked at your own code to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: nextDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: nextDate))
```